# How to add items back to an ArrayList after appending to StringBuilder?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, stringbuilder

```java
ArrayList<String> itemslist = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String item : itemslist) {
     stringBuilder.append(item);
     stringBuilder.append("\n");
}
String textArray = stringBuilder.toString();
```

What is the way to create an ArrayList from textArray again? Because I add the textArray to SQLite since SQLite does not accept an Array, but in this way I can add the items to database, but don't know how to make an array again when I retrieve them from SQLite.

Comment: Your code can combine multiple Strings into one, but just imagine what happens if the String contains a `\n` character? If you later try to parse the data you are unable to reconstruct the original strings as you don't know if the `\n` is a separator character or a character of the string. Therefore I strings recommend not to implement such an enoding7decoding yourself unless you are 100% sure that it is impossible that your separator char is contained in the strings (e.g. by applying a whitelist regex scan on them and reject everything if it does not match).

Comment: Thank you, got your point , but what if I set the EditText MaxLine to 1 line, does this fix the problem? In case if the user break the line. Is this the only solution?

Comment: I would not count o it. So you have three possibilities: test each user input with a regex and reject it when it contains an `\n`, filter out all `\n` characters of all input strings or as third possibility escape all `\n` characters.

Comment: Glad you helped me to know the posibilites regarding reconstructing the origional Sring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the `String` at the line breaks, you can try this:

```java
String[] arraySplit = textArray.split("\n");
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arraySplit));
```

### *Edit*

Be aware of the comment from @Robert, since this will split the given `String` on **every** line break char.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I was about to ask you how to add textArray to ArrayList, but you edited the answer and I got what I want. Thanks again.